# Reading ELF header of loaded shared object during runtime

Tags: linux, process, mapping, shared-libraries, elf

I wrote some code to search for a symbol in a shared library's ELF header. The code works if I parse the shared object file stored on my disk.

Now, I wanted to use this code to parse the ELF header of a loaded shared library. As an example the libdl library is mapped into the current process:

```
b7735000-b7738000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 315560     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
b7738000-b7739000 r--p 00002000 08:01 315560     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
b7739000-b773a000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 315560     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

The (first) mapping of the address contains the ELF header. I tried to read this header and to extract the *dlopen* symbol in the *.dynsym* section. However, the header is slightly different from the one of the 'plain' .so file on the disk. For example the offset of the *.shstrtab* version is 0. Therefore, it is not possible to get the name of a section.

I wanted to ask why the ELF header is changed during loading of the library and where I can find the 'missing' sections. Is it even possible to parse the ELF header after the library was loaded?
Does anybody know any article explaining the layout of a shared library/its ELF header when it is mapped into a process?

Currently I'm using following functions to iterate over the ELF header. If *libdl_start* points to the memory mapped *libdl.so.2* file, the code works fine. However, if it points to the region mapped by the linker, *get_dynstr_section* does not find the *dynstr* section.

```
int get_libdl_functions()
{
    Elf32_Ehdr *ehdr = libdl_start;
    Elf32_Shdr *shdr, *shdrs_start = (Elf32_Shdr *)(((char *)ehdr) + ehdr->e_shoff);
    Elf32_Sym *symbol, *symbols_start;
    char *strtab = get_dynstr_section();
    int sec_it = 0, sym_it = 0;

    rt_info->dlopen = NULL;
    rt_info->dlsym = NULL;

    if(strtab == NULL)
        return -1;

    for(sec_it = 0; sec_it < ehdr->e_shnum; ++sec_it) {
        // Iterate over all sections to find .dynsym
        shdr = shdrs_start + sec_it;
        if(shdr->sh_type == SHT_DYNSYM)
        {
            // Ok we found the right section
            symbols_start = (Elf32_Sym *)(((char *)ehdr) + shdr->sh_offset);
            for(sym_it = 0; sym_it < shdr->sh_size / sizeof(Elf32_Sym); ++sym_it) {
                symbol = symbols_start + sym_it;
                if(ELF32_ST_TYPE(symbol->st_info) != STT_FUNC)
                    continue;

                if(strncmp(strtab + symbol->st_name, DL_OPEN_NAME, sizeof DL_OPEN_NAME) && !rt_info->dlopen) {
                    //printf("Offset of dlopen: 0x%x\n", symbol->st_value);
                    dlopen = ((char *)ehdr) + symbol->st_value;
                } else if(strncmp(strtab + symbol->st_name, DL_SYM_NAME, sizeof DL_SYM_NAME) && !rt_info->dlsym) {
                    //printf("Offset of dlsym: 0x%x\n", symbol->st_value);
                    dlsym = ((char *)ehdr) + symbol->st_value;
                }

                if(dlopen != 0 && dlsym != 0)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

void *get_dynstr_section()
{
    Elf32_Ehdr *ehdr = libdl_start;
    Elf32_Shdr *shdr, *shdrs_start = (Elf32_Shdr *)(((char *)ehdr) + ehdr->e_shoff);
    char *strtab = ((char *)ehdr) + ((shdrs_start + ehdr->e_shstrndx))->sh_offset;
    int sec_it = 0;

    for(sec_it = 0; sec_it < ehdr->e_shnum; ++sec_it) {
        // Iterate over all sections to find .dynstr section
        shdr = shdrs_start + sec_it;
        if(shdr->sh_type == SHT_STRTAB && strncmp(strtab + shdr->sh_name, DYNSTR_NAME, sizeof DYNSTR_NAME))
            return ((char *)ehdr) + shdr->sh_offset;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the ELF header is changed during loading of the library

It *isn't*. Your question is based on false assumption, but since you didn't show any actual code, it's hard to guess what you've done wrong.

**Update:**

In this code:

```
*shdrs_start = (Elf32_Shdr *)(((char *)ehdr) + ehdr->e_shoff);
```

you assume that sections headers are loaded into memory. But sections headers are *not required* at runtime, and if they end up loaded into memory, it's only by accident.

You need to read them into memory from disk (or `mmap` them) yourself, using the `e_shoff` you got from `ehdr`.

Comment: I added the code I'm using to iterate the ELF header to the original question.

Comment: @PraMiD As far as I understand, your problem is that "`get_dynstr_section` does not find the dynstr section". Yet you didn't show *its* code. How do you expect anyone to help you? You should try to construct a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The code of `get_dynstr_section` is contained in the question. Right after `get_libdl_functions`

Comment: Sorry I had no time to answer the last week.
@Employed Russion: Thanks for your answer! I agree with you that there is no reason to load the ELF headers into memory.

Nevertheless, I've made the observation that Linux always loads a header into memory (I am able to read parts of it), but it is different from the one on the disk. I.e., it is shorter and some parts, like the shstrtab, are 'missing'.

Is there any reason for this behavior or is it just by accident as you said?

Comment: @PraMiD The ELF *header* is always loaded, the *section* headers aren't.

Answer (score 3):

You do NOT need to mmap the shared library again - the system already did it- but you cannot rely on the section headers.  The section headers are only for the linking view of an ELF file and often aren't allocated into a program segment.  You will need to look at it from the execution view. The section .dynstr is always loaded into memory.  Otherwise dynamic linking wouldn't work. To get at it, go through the program headers to find the PT_DYNAMIC segment. It will have elements DT_SYMTAB and DT_STRTAB that correspond to .dynsym and .dynstr.  You may also have to adjust the address values using a base address. It's very common especially with ASLR for shared objects to be mapped at different virtual addresses than they were linked at.  You can find this adjustment amount by subtracting the lowest virtual address in a PT_LOAD entry from the lowest mapped segment in the memory map. Or even better use the link map maintained by ld.so. It contains the base address, the path of the shared object, and a pointer to the shared object's dynamic area. Consult  for how this is laid out.  If you are running Linux, you might be very interested in the function dl_iterate_phdr(). It's great for finding things about the libraries mapped into the current process image. If you want to examine another process you have to roll your own.

Comment: I tried to say consult "<link.h>" for how the linkmap is laid out