# Segfault when reading ELF Shdr of own executable

Tags: c++, elf

I'm trying to read the symbol table of the program's own ELF binary as part of a symbolizer. Part of this involves finding the ELF start, then ELF shdr, etc. I must be doing something wrong, though, because despite `e_shoff` matching what I see by `readelf`ing the binary manually and the start address looking reasonable, I cannot read the shdr.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int findELFStartCallback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size,
                                void *data) {
  static_cast<void>(size);
  static int address_found = 0;
  if (address_found) {
    return 0;
  }
  address_found = 1;
  fprintf(stderr, "relocation: 0x%lx\n", (long)info->dlpi_addr);
  for (ElfW(Half) i = 0; i < info->dlpi_phnum; i++) {
    if (info->dlpi_phdr[i].p_type == PT_LOAD) {
      auto result = reinterpret_cast<void *>(info->dlpi_addr +
                                             info->dlpi_phdr[i].p_vaddr);
      fprintf(stderr, "a.out loaded at %p\n", result);
      *reinterpret_cast<void **>(data) = result;
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

static void *findELFStart() {
  void *result = nullptr;
  dl_iterate_phdr(findELFStartCallback, &result);
  return result;
}

static void checkELF(ElfW(Ehdr) * ehdr) {
  assert(ehdr->e_ident[EI_MAG0] == ELFMAG0 && "bad magic number");
  assert(ehdr->e_ident[EI_MAG1] == ELFMAG1 && "bad magic number");
  assert(ehdr->e_ident[EI_MAG2] == ELFMAG2 && "bad magic number");
  assert(ehdr->e_ident[EI_MAG3] == ELFMAG3 && "bad magic number");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *exe_ = nullptr;
  exe_ = reinterpret_cast<char *>(findELFStart());
  assert(exe_ != nullptr && "could not find ELF header");
  checkELF(reinterpret_cast<ElfW(Ehdr) *>(exe_));
  auto elf = reinterpret_cast<ElfW(Ehdr) *>(exe_);
  fprintf(stderr, "e_shoff is %ld (0x%lx)\n", elf->e_shoff, elf->e_shoff);
  auto shdr = reinterpret_cast<ElfW(Shdr) *>(exe_ + elf->e_shoff);
  fprintf(stderr, "shdr is %ld (%p)\n", (size_t)shdr, (void*)shdr);
  const char *str = exe_ + shdr[elf->e_shstrndx].sh_offset;  // boom
}
```

I get a segfault. When I load it in GDB, it looks like `shdr` is indeed a bad pointer. What am I missing here?

Sample output:

```
computer% ./p/dladdr                                                 
relocation: 0x0
a.out loaded at 0x400000
e_shoff is 24528 (0x5fd0)
shdr is 4218832 (0x405fd0)
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./p/dladdr
computer%
```

EDIT: After seeing [Reading ELF header of loaded shared object during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836594/reading-elf-header-of-loaded-shared-object-during-runtime) maybe the sections just aren't loaded into memory...

EDIT: I finished the symbolizer and it's available [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/cinder/blob/b43345d3c561829014366608fdaa0e4f92210742/Jit/symbolizer.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe the sections just aren't loaded into memory...

That's exactly right. Here is `readelf -WS /bin/date` on my system:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000000318 000318 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.gnu.property NOTE            0000000000000338 000338 000050 00   A  0   0  8
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000000388 000388 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            00000000000003ac 0003ac 000020 00   A  0   0  4
...
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          000000000001a0a0 019098 000130 00  WA  0   0 32
  [27] .gnu.build.attributes NOTE            000000000001c1d0 019098 000248 00      0   0  4
  [28] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 0192e0 000024 00      0   0  4
  [29] .gnu_debugdata    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 019304 0005a0 00      0   0  1
  [30] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0198a4 00013e 00      0   0  1
```

Note that `.shstrtab` does not have the `A` (allocated) flag. The contents of this section is not used at runtime, so there is *no reason* to load it into memory, and so it isn't.

If you want to access `.shstrtab`, you need to either `read` it from the file on disk, or `mmap` the entire file (the kernel only `mmap`s the parts covered by `PT_LOAD` segments, not the entire file).

Comment: Thank you! This answer and your other many answers about ELF across the site helped me finish the symbolizer: https://github.com/facebookincubator/cinder/blob/b43345d3c561829014366608fdaa0e4f92210742/Jit/symbolizer.cpp